# facing #fillNegs during deployment of next.js webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, tailwind-css

During deploying my next.js app I am facing following #fillNegs in the tailwind node_modules folder. I am using node.js version 12.22.0 and next.js version 11. and Tailwind version is 2.0.2

```
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3 ./src/ProductDisplay/index.module.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[2].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[2].use[2]!./src/ProductDisplay/index.module.css
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3 /usr/src/app/node_modules/tailwindcss/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/ast.js:86
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3     #fillNegs() {
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3              ^
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3 > Build error occurred
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3 Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:397:19
module.image.null_resource.push (local-exec): #15 147.3     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
```

Comment: are you using rimraf?

Comment: @Quak_2023 yes I am using rimraf version 2.6.2 for cleaning that cache in node_modules before starting to serve the build. But I removed this rimraf command and then tried it, then also same issue is coming. Do you want me to completely uninstall the rimraf from the project ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version of Node your using is not supported [see github issue](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf/issues/265) the min version is Node 14. so you can either remove rimraf or just update Node version to something higher then 14